# How can you review the response content of ASP MVC 5 calls using Glimpse?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, glimpse

I'm working on a web project using ASP MVC 5 and Razor, and am currently using Glimpse to help inspect requests during development.

I've been using the Glimpse HUD and extended gui to view request data, but I can't seem to find how to view the actual response data that the client receives. The responses are simple POST calls returning JSON content. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glimpse collects a lot of information while processing the request but the response is not one of them, therefore you won't find a tab showing you that information.

If you would like to see the response, then you can use the developer tools of the browser you are using and have a look at the network tab.